# Naive Bayes non-Dictionary Term in Test Document

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

Using Laplacian Smoothing we can get rid of 0 probabilities if a term occur in spam and does not occur in ham class or vice versa. My question is about what if a term in test document does not occur in training dataset(i.e. in dictionary). For example if we extend example in page 44 in ->  http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/naivebayes.pdf as follows:

(Consider only change is test document part)

Test    5    Chinese    Chinese    Chinese    Tokyo    Japan    Greek    ?

P(c|d5)'s calculation requires P(Greek|c). However since Greek doesn't exist in dictionary we didn't calculate it before. What should P(Greek|c)'s and P(Greek|j)'s value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common solution is to treat tokens seen less than $n$ times (across all classes) as a special "unknown" or "rare" token. You then use this probability to assign values to legitimately unknown known words.

You certainly don't want to assign zero probability to all classes when you encounter a novel word. This avoids that issue, and captures the idea that different classes may have different amounts of out-of-dictionary words.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to map all of the unknown words to some token like . Then you can assign some probability to that token for each of your classes.

Comment: As I understand, value does not matter. However, for example If a test document has a lot of unknown terms, high value for unknown terms affect results as reward; low value for unknown terms affect results as penalty. Doesn't it? Can proof it by using equations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by high value and by reward.

Comment: If assigned probability value to the unknown words(which is same for all of them as you said) is high, P(c|d5) will be high; otherwise P(c|d5) will be low. I meant in my first comment, is this fair when we compare documents which contain any non-dictionary terms with documents which contain a lot of non-dictionary terms?

Comment: Similar to my question, but the reason is not clear, discussion in -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680243/implementation-of-naive-bayes-accuracy-issues
In accepted answer in case 5 and in explanation says: "First, if the word has never been observed in some set, the probability of the message in it should decrease. Ignoring the word is not a good idea, you need to account for it as a highly unprobable one." but why?

Comment: That's the whole point. If unknown words are associated more with class c than with class j then you would want P(c|d5) to be high when the document has unknown words. You have to learn the probability of unknown words for each class using held-out data.

Comment: I understood from the message that i copied [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680243/implementation-of-naive-bayes-accuracy-issues), P(Greek|c) and P(Greek|j) must be very low probaility, for example 0.00000001. But in here  [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32614/including-missing-words-when-applying-naive-bayes-in-document-classification) they simply ignored missing words. Also you said I have to learn unknown words probability using held-out(?) data. What is held-out data? Is it training set? That was the problem, we do not have unknown words in it. I'm very confused.

Comment: held-out means held-out from the training. That way it has unknown words.