# Possible Problem in Naive Bayes Spam Filters

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I realized that, never been observed words in training sets, decrease test probaility of documents being spam and not spam after i mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98986/naive-bayes-non-dictionary-term-in-test-document) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680243/implementation-of-naive-bayes-accuracy-issues) "... you need to account for it as a highly unprobable one." was helpful.

I think it is an important problem. Spammers might use this by adding their spam mails, words probably not in mail corporations dictionary (for example using rarely used languages words, meaningless words etc. ) Isn't this a big problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this technique is called [Bayesian Poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_poisoning) and it is a big problem. Often these words are added with a font size of zero or with white text so that the recipient doesn't notice. Sometimes they will also use gibberish as well.